# Django rest_framework quantity is not incrementing in ecommerce project

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## models.py

```
class Cartlist(models.
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
class Items(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cartlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    order = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.product)
```

## Views.py

```
class AddCartView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset =  Items.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AddCartSerializer
```

## Serializer.py

```
class AddCartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Items
        fields = ['product']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user 
        product = self.validated_data['product'] 
        if Cartlist.objects.filter(user=user):
            item = Items.objects.filter(cart__user=user,product=product)
            if item:
                item.quantity += 1
                item.save()
                return item
            else:
                item = Items.objects.create(cart=Cartlist.objects.get(user=user),**validated_data)
                item.save()
                return item
        
        else:
            cart = Cartlist.objects.create(user=user)
            cart.save()
            item = Items.objects.create(cart=cart,**validated_data)
            item.save()
            return item
```

[Exception Value:'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'quantity'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rUVI.png)

if the product is already exists, then increment the quantity field by 1. Default value is 1 if the user add same product into their cart list the product quantity must be increment by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
item = Items.objects.filter(cart__user=user,product=product)
if item:
    item.quantity += 1
    item.save()
    return item
```

[`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) is returning `Queryset` of objects (list of objects) even if here is only one object in query result. In other words `filter` returns `items`, but not `item`
If you want to get single item, you have to use one of constructions below:

- `Items.objects.get(cart__user=user,product=product)` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get))
- `Items.objects.filter(cart__user=user,product=product).first()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#first))

Comment: [rzlvmp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13946204/rzlvmp) "Items.objects.filter(cart__user=user,product=product).first()" accepted this answer

Answer (score 0):

This code is not working because you are trying fetch quantity from QuerySet which is not possible you should use

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = self.context['request'].user 
    product = self.validated_data['product'] 
    if Cartlist.objects.filter(user=user):
        item = Items.objects.filter(cart__user=user,product=product).first()
        if item:
            item.quantity += 1
            item.save()
            return item
        else:
            item = Items.objects.create(cart=Cartlist.objects.get(user=user),**validated_data)
            item.save()
            return item
    
    else:
        cart = Cartlist.objects.create(user=user)
        cart.save()
        item = Items.objects.create(cart=cart,**validated_data)
        item.save()
        return item
```

OR you can also use

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = self.context['request'].user 
    product = self.validated_data['product'] 
    if Cartlist.objects.filter(user=user):
        item = Items.objects.filter(cart__user=user,product=product)
        if item:
            item.update(quantity=F("quantity")+1) 
            return item
        else:
            item = Items.objects.create(cart=Cartlist.objects.get(user=user),**validated_data)
            item.save()
            return item
    
    else:
        cart = Cartlist.objects.create(user=user)
        cart.save()
        item = Items.objects.create(cart=cart,**validated_data)
        item.save()
        return item
```

Comment: [Lakshit Khanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10083810/lakshit-khanna)
 "
item = Items.objects.filter(cart__user=user,product=product).first() 
if item:
            item.quantity += 1
            item.save()
            return item
"
accepted this answer
"item.update(quantity=F("quantity")) " not working properly for me.can u share this idea. this is new method for me

Comment: @JerinRaju you need to import F from django.db.models to use it and the statement should be ```item.update(quantity=F("quantity")+1)```

Comment: [Lakshit Khanna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10083810/lakshit-khanna) thank you